# TimelineTile misalignment

Tags: user-interface, flutter

I need a hand. I used the component: TimelineTile but unfortunately I have some information alignment problems.
As you can see from the screen, I need to align the word Line and I need the first word "BLABLABLABLA" to wrap.
Do I bring you the code where I'm wrong?
Thank you all.
Vincenzo
[image: Error image]

I add the code that I have implemented.
The information is loaded dynamically, from a list

```
child: ListView.builder(
          itemExtent: 90.0,
          itemCount: viewModel.detailTrainModel.listStopModel.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            if(index==0){
              return TimelineTile(
                alignment: TimelineAlign.manual,
                lineX: 0.1,
                isFirst: true,
                rightChild: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("12:00",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.orange),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 37, 60, 1)),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Line",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 37, 60, 1)),),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              );
            }
            else if(index == (viewModel.detailTrainModel.listStopModel.length-1)){
              return TimelineTile(
                alignment: TimelineAlign.manual,
                lineX: 0.1,
                isFirst: false,
                isLast: true,
                rightChild: 
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.orange),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("BLABLA",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 37, 60, 1)),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Line",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 37, 60, 1)),),
                    ),
                  ],
                  ),

              );
            }
            else{
              return TimelineTile(
                alignment: TimelineAlign.manual,
                lineX: 0.1,
                rightChild: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("13:00",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.orange),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("BLABLA",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 37, 60, 1)),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Line",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, 
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 37, 60, 1)),),
                    ), 
                    ],
                  ),
              );
            }
          },
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this part with an `Expanded` widget and use `maxLines` property to enable wrapping:

```
Container(
  child: Text("BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 37, 60, 1)),),
),
```

Updated code:

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    child: Text(
      "BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA",
      maxLines: 5,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(74, 37, 60, 1)),
    ),
  ),
),
```

You can set `maxLines` to `null` to show the entire string.

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much, it seems that I have solved even if I have to tell you the truth it gave me the word "Line" attached to the edge, I had to insert a padding to be able to space but I am not sure that it is the correct solution

Comment: It's better to add the padding to the right side of 'Line' because the middle text can be long and mess up you alignment again.